# How to I search for the definition of a function without a name

Tags: c++

I was trying to understand a cpp program when I encounter this:
`has_image =(*kinfu_) (depth_device_)`.

I am trying to understand what the function does,  but without any name I am unable to search for the function definition.

Do you guys have any suggestion on how I should go about searching of it's definition?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`kinfu_` is likely a *function pointer* whose whole purpose is that it doesn't have a single possible value, but multiple ones. You need to find the place where its value was set, and that will lead you to the concrete function being executed.

You can also use a debugger to print the value of `kinfu_`, which will also print out the name of its current function value.

`kinfu_` could also be a pointer to an instance of a class that defines `operator()`, in which case you need to find the definition of the member.

Comment: Thanks! This really gave me some light on where to start looking

Answer (score 0):

Search the code for `kinfu_`. It's probably a data member of the class. My guess is that `kinfu_` is a pointer to a functor, e.g.:

```
struct SomeFunctor {
    bool operator()(float depth) { … }
};
⋮
class SomeClass {
    ⋮
private:
    SomeFunctor * kinfu_;
    ⋮
};
```